# Using group_by with checkboxGroupInput in simple Shiny example

Tags: r, group-by, shiny, dplyr

I was trying to use group_by with an input from checkboxGroupInput in a simple shiny app shown below.

I was expecting that if I checked 2 boxes (Cylinders and Gears) that I would get the same output as I get when I run this:

```
   mtcars%>%
     group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
     count()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl, gear [8]
    cyl  gear     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2
```

Here is the simple shiny app.  How would I mimic the above output when I check the boxes that are created from the below code?

```
# UI
    ui <- fluidPage(


  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                     c("Cylinders"    = "cyl",
                       "Transmission" = "am",
                       "Gears"        = "gear"
                       )
                     ),
  tableOutput("data")
)


# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$data <- renderTable({

      mtcars %>%
        group_by(!!as.name(input$variable)) %>%
        count()

      },
    rownames = TRUE)

  } # Server function close


# Run the app
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `server`, we can change it to `group_by_at` which takes string input and it would accommodate more than one group variable input by wrapping with `vars`

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$data <- renderTable({

     mtcars %>%
         group_by_at(vars(input$variable)) %>%
         count()

      },
     rownames = TRUE)

  }
```

---

Also, in the OP's code, `group_by` could potentially take more than one groups, so we can convert to symbol with `syms`  (more multiple elements) and then evaluate (`!!!`).  If we use `sym` and `!!`, it would work only for one variable at a time

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$data <- renderTable({

    mtcars %>%
      group_by(!!! rlang::syms(input$variable)) %>%
      count()

  },
    rownames = TRUE)

}
```

-output

[image]